# Setting the header referrer on Primefaces action

Tags: jsf, primefaces, csrf

This is a follow up to a previous question: [Error using JSF protected views when opening a new tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51861619/error-using-jsf-protected-views-when-opening-a-new-tab/51881009#51881009)

I am using faces-config protected views to protect against CSRF. I ran into problems earlier with links opened in a new tab that I resolved by adding

```
rel="noopener noreferrer"
```

to all new tab links.

But now I' running into the same issue with commandButtons.

I have

```
        <p:commandButton value="Submit" 
            action="#{bean.submit}" />
```

And submit() returns a string with the new view. But I still get the following error:

```
javax.faces.application.ProtectedViewException: JSF1099: Referer [sic] header value http://.../updatestatus.xhtml?javax.faces.Token=1534516398157&cr=45309 does not appear to be a protected view. Preventing display of viewId /finance/commitmentregister/view.xhtml
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.maybeTakeProtectedViewAction(Unknown Source)
```

Is there a way to set no referer or opener on the Primefaces commandbutton?

Edit:

Maybe not the answer I was looking for, but I got around the problem by adding a servlet request wrapper in a filter to return null when asked for the referer.

Further edit:

Adding the rough outline of how my code looks with the wrapper fix:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "UserLoginFilter", urlPatterns = { "*.xhtml" })
public class UserLoginFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequestWrapper wrapper = new HttpServletRequestWrapper(httpServletRequest) {
        @Override
        public String getHeader(String name) {
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("referer")) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return super.getHeader(name);
            }
        }
    };

    chain.doFilter(wrapper, response);
}

}
```

Comment: I am confused though all Ajax requests from Command button are already CRSF protected by the ViewState right?

Comment: @Holden - could you post the code for your servlet request filter? I've a similar issue

Comment: @emeraldjava Sure thing. Updated post.